# Javascript jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i was trying to make a ui to make html window elements and when i run this script this is what happens an error comes up saying. I'm running this on the chrome browser on a chromebook.

> Javascript jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
  function createwindow(settings) {
      var draggableclass = "";
      if (settings == undefined) {
        var settings = {};
      }
      if (settings.content == undefined) {
        settings.content = "";
      }
      if (settings.closecolour == undefined) {
        settings.closecolour = "#ffffff";
      }
      if (settings.requirejs == undefined) {
        settings.requirejs = "";
      }
      if (settings.windowcolour == undefined) {
        settings.windowcolour = "#000000";
      }
      if (settings.width == undefined) {
        settings.width = 200;
      }
      if (settings.height == undefined) {
        settings.height = 400;
      }
      if (settings.appname == undefined) {
        settings.appname = "Untitled App";
      }
      if (settings.bodycolour == undefined) {
        settings.bodycolour = "#ffffff";
      }
      if (settings.icon == undefined) {
        settings.icon = "http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i45241/iconleak/stainless/script.ico";
      }
      if (settings.titlecolour == undefined) {
        settings.titlecolour = "#ffffff";
      }
      var requirejs = '';
        var appname = settings.appname.replace(" ", "-");
      var closexy = settings.width - 14;
        closexy = settings.width - 24;
        draggableclass = "draggable";
      var appid = '"#' + appname + '"';
        var app = "<div style='border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-bottom-width:26px;border-color:#000000;width:" + settings.width + "px;height:" + settings.height + "px;' id='" + appname + "' class='app'><div class='top " + draggableclass + "' style='width:" + settings.width + "px;background-color:" + settings.windowcolour + ";height:25px;'><img style='height:24px; width:24px;' src='" + settings.icon + "' /><text style='position:absolute;top:3px;color:" + settings.titlecolour + ";'>" + settings.appname + "</text><i style='color:" + settings.closecolour + ";position:absolute;left:" + closexy + ";' class='material-icons icon icon-button close-button' onclick='$(" + appid + ").remove()'>close</i></div><div style='background-color:" + settings.bodycolour + ";height:100%;width:100%;overflow:scroll;' class='innerapp'>" + settings.content + "</div></div>";
        $('body').append(app);
          $("#" + appname).draggable();
         if (settings.length > 0) {


      }
        requirejs = settings.requirejs;
        var nstr = requirejs.split("|");
        if (nstr.length == 1) {
          $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[0])
        .appendTo('head');
    });
        }
        else if (nstr.length == 2) {
            $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[0])
        .appendTo('head');
    });
        $(function () {
     $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[1])
        .appendTo('head');
    });

        }
         else if (nstr.length == 3) {
        $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[0])
        .appendTo('head');
    });
        $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[1])
        .appendTo('head');
    });
        $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        attr('src', nstr[2])
        .appendTo('head');
    });

        }
        else if (nstr.length == 4) {
          $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[0])
        .appendTo('head');
    });
        $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[1])
        .appendTo('head');
    });
        $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[2])
        .appendTo('head');
    });
        $(function () {
      $('<' + 'script' + '>')
        .attr('src', nstr[3])
        .appendTo('head');
    });

        }
    }




    function codemirroraddon(addon) {
      var script = "<script src='codemirror/addon/" + addon + "'></script>";
      $("head").append(script);
    }
    function codemirroraddoncss(addon) {
      var css = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='codemirror/addon/" + addon + "' />";
      $("head").append(css);
    }


    function injectjs() {
      var userinput = jseditor.doc.getValue();
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.innerHTML = "" + userinput;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

Comment: Is this the code that you having an error?

Comment: yes this the code thats having an error

Comment: is this `$('<' + 'script' + '>')` a valid jQuery selector ?.. maybe Not...

Comment: because as for my understanding `.min` js in not like this

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's the minified version that's showing the error, no?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVedi That would show a jQuery error, not a JS syntax error I believe.

Comment: A couple of quick things. You don't have to check for undefined if you are just going to set it anyway. Also the way that you are selecting your creating your script tags is not correct.

Comment: i was previously using `$('<script>')` and it came up with the same error

Comment: its $('script'). And the error is most likely due to the way the code is written.